# Annoying selection problem that can't be googled because it's conflated with irrelevant results

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools

For some reason, I don't know how, when I'm in edit mode, my cursor is always a white circle. How do I revert to the more convenient selection mode that's there by default?

Comment: Great, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press the <kbd>W</kbd> (selection mode) key. You will see the selection mode change at the top of the icons on the left bar (the order is Box > Circle > Lasso > Tweak). Keep pressing W to toggle through them. Default is "Box" (meaning you will have to press <kbd>W</kbd> 3 times to get back to "normal"):

[image: Select]